# Java: Writing to a Scala Output Stream

Tags: java, scala, stream, buffer, stdout

I'm working on a project that requires me to run an instance of scala using the Process class. To do this I execute the following code:

```
Process process = RunTime.getRunTime().exec("<path to scala binary> <scala file>");
```

This call gives me a process representative of the scala program that is executing. I am able to access the process's input stream and receive input from the process with:

```
BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
stdin.readLine();
```

The scala program I am trying to run involves a Scanner which picks up input and prints it out. When I try to register a BufferedWriter to the OutputStreamWriter that is generated from process.getOutputStream(), and then write to that stream with:

```
stdout.write("Hello");
```

The scala program does not receive this input, and I was wondering: why does this occur?

Comment: Are you flushing the input (`stdout.flush()`)?

Comment: That was the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I forgot to flush the stream.